# Have object and its shadow behind object appear in front

Tags: image, shadowcatcher

I have an images as planes in my scene that I am adding on to. I lines up a plane with the floor in the image, and want to add assets to make it seem as if they are on the floor. The plane is blocking the object (as anything normally does) but I want objects behind it (and their shadows) to be visible[image]

I want the car to go behind the plane and appear in front, so that  it looks like it is on the ground in the picture. I also want it to have its shadow to add realism. Any way to do this?

[image]

I want it to act like the behind option that you have with reference images, where you can have it so that the object always appears in front of the reference image. However, I want the image to render as well so I do not have that option.

[image]

I want it to act like this, where the cube is behind the image but appears in front. (Excuse the randomness of the example, I am on a different computer.)

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Compositing sounds like a good option.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Any suggestions or resources on how to do it?

Comment: @Relevred i’m not sure, since I did not fully understand the layout of order. You said you wanted the car to “go behind the plane and appear in the front,” and I have little idea what that means.

Comment: I want it so that its behind the picture, but appears in front with its shadow. I want this because I have a plane matching the ground and I want to be able  to position objects on it so that it appears to be in the picture. I will add the blend file

Comment: Maybe you want a **shadow catcher**? Or maybe you want to bake a shadow into a plane and then move that plane together with the car? If you want a more complex shadow, then you need geometry as in Blunder's answer.

Comment: The car is 3d, the image is not. I want to make it seem as if the car is in the image, and I want to do that by placing it on a plane and making it appear as if it was in front. I would appreciate answers that I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the 3D car in a 2D image, you need to model some geometry.

Use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> in *Edit* mode) on the background image that you have. Cut out the shapes of the pole/lantern, the tower, the wall, and the stairs. Cut it, then select the faces, duplicate them (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+(<kbd>D</kbd>) and separate them (<kbd>P</kbd>). Add a *Soldify* modifier and a *Bevel* modifier to the new object cut out.

For the tree, you only need half of the vertical outline. Then use the *Screw* modifier. While doing so, check the correct face orientation and origin.

Extrude the floor and correct the texture mapping in the UV editor if necessary. For the wall in any case. Add a *Bump* node to the stair's material. Set up a few lights.

Done. The car is now in the "image".

[image: 2D to 3D screen]

Comment: So why the downvote?

Comment: Great post, but this isn't relevant to my problem. I added more details because there seems to be some confusion

Comment: And the car is 3d, I noticed this was a common mistake